# Spring security oauth2 login url 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring security oauth2 app that uses spring security with it. The configuration looks like this

Here is my WebConfig.java file

```
loginOrigin = "http://localhost:3000";
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage(loginOrigin + "/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureHandler(new LoginFailureHandler(loginOrigin + "/login?error=true"))
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginEntryPoint(loginOrigin));

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

As you can see the loginOrigin points the login page to an external react app.

Within the react app I have a proxy set so that requests for localhost:3000 go to localhost:8080

My question is when I try to access http://localhost:8080/login directly, it always comes back with a 404. I am able to access other url's like http://localhost:8080/register in my app. It is just the login url that I am having this issue with.

However when I have my react app up and running and do a http://localhost:3000/login it works fine.

Can you let me know why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing directly"? Are you expecting that your loginProcessingUrl endpoint will return a view?

Comment: So accessing directly meaning 1. Using postman 2. I have the react app that is deployed and I have a proxy setting to call this login endpoint. The loginProcessingUrl will do a redirect as I am using this in addition to OAuth2.0

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
```